# How to style an entire row in a Blazorise datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, blazor, blazorise

Is it possible to style an entire row in a Blazorise datagrid conditionally?
for example, if Active == false, I want to gray out an entire row, using css

```
.inactive {
    text-color: gray;
}
```

I tried to use the RowStyling attribute but I am not sure how to use that (or if it can be used at all). If it can be used, I would like to pass the current TItem to the function. I can set the style at the row level () and use CSS to set global row colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `RowStyling` parameter. Example:

```
<DataGrid ...
          RowStyling="@OnRowStyling"

private void OnRowStyling(Employee employee, DataGridRowStyling styling)
{
    if (!employee.IsActive)
        styling.Class = "inactive";
}
```

Change Employee with your own model.